# S3 Object URL - Downloading partial file (19MB / 100MB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, filesize

I have a windows application installer file (.exe) saved on an s3 bucket. The size of that file is 100MB as indicated in the s3 console.

I also have a website where I make the object URL of that .exe available to certain users (i.e., https://s3.(region).amazonaws.com/(Bucket)/(instllerName).exe. In the past the object URL was sufficient for a user to get the installer onto their local machine. Now, what's happening instead is the object URL only downloads a partial file (19MB) to my machine.

If I go through the S3 console and click the "download" button
[image]

It downloads the full 100mb to my computer just fine, but as soon as I use the object URL - it gives me the partial file.

I have another mac installer (.dmg) that is also 100MB in a different s3 directory in the same bucket. For that file, the object URL works just fine. It's just this .exe file that has this issue.

Anyone else encountered this?

-I've tried re-uploading the file to s3 in case it may be corrupted on s3 itself.
-I've tried adding metadata to the file in s3 to indicate it is an application
-I've explored using the AWS cli to download the file instead of the object URL, but that just seems like a bandaid - this should be working.

Comment: you're absolutely sure you've got the right object url?

Comment: The only difference between using the URL directly and the download link in the console is the download link presigns the URL to mark it as an attachment.  If you compare the two URLs they should byte-for-byte identical up to the start of the query parameters.  Have you done that comparison?

Comment: @erik258 I'm absolutely sure I've got the right object URL. I've quadruple checked that, and have the added knowledge that this same URL functioned in the past and nothing about the URL has changed since those successful iterations.

Comment: @AnonCoward Great suggestion. I just compared them and while the URLs are the same, I did notice that one of the headers changes. In the object URL request the content-length is 20676608 (about 20MB) bytes, but in the download URL request the content-length is the expected 105589205 (about 100 MB). That looks like the crux of the problem. I'm going to dig more.

Comment: How are you requesting the object URL that's causing a (short) content-length header to be sent? It's optional. Why would your HTTP client send it?

Comment: @jarmod All I'm doing is clicking on the "Object URL" link in the aws console for this particular file. I watch the network tab while it processes and check the header of the network request for that download.

Comment: The "Object URL" link only ever contains a URL to the object without any query params.  The download link generated doesn't include the content-length.  How are you getting a URL with the content-length specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I didn't necessarily find the REASON for this oddity. But I did find a way to address it.

I discovered that it was ONLY that particular filename that was causing issues. If I saved my desired file as any other name it worked fine. So I just changed the name.

Maybe that will help someone else!

Comment: Did the installer file name happen to have any unusual characters in it, such as `+`?  Did you compare S3 access log entries for failed and succeeded downloads?

Comment: Would be nice to understand the root cause here. Hard to imagine that it's simply the key of the downloaded object.